# Nested Vector in linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I choose (a) but I am not sure if anyone explain that MCQ 
Let T1(v1, v2) = (v1 - v2, v1 + v2) and T2(v1, v2) = (2v2, 2v1). The value of T1(T2(v1,v2)) is

a) (2v2 + 2v1, 2v1 - 2v2)

b)(2v2 - 2v1, 2v1 + 2v2)

c)(2v1 - 2v2, 2v1 + 2v2)

d) (2v1 + 2v2, 2v1 - 2v2)
please look at the picture link

[click to see the image  here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5GOG.png)

Comment: Write down the question in the body of your post, and explain your reasoning

Comment: done >>please help me know

Comment: $(v_1,v_2) \to (2v_2,2v_1)\to (2v_2-2v_1,2v_2+2v_1)\to b)$

Comment: Not done, you didn't explain your reasoning for chosing a

Comment: I replace the value of T1 with the value of T2 

because T2 =( 2v2 ,---)    -----> I choose 2v2+2v1  as v2
and because (----, 2v1)  ------> I choose 2v1-2v2 
I just substitute and guess